# Sorting an array of objects by field makes no difference

Tags: php, arrays, function, sorting

I have this array called `$pages`. Inside, we have objects with several fields. One of these fields is `title`.

I want to sort alphabetically by `title`.

Inside a class called `PLUGIN_PAGES` I declare this...

```
public function mySort($a, $b)
{
return $a->title < $b->title;
}
```

inside another method I call

```
 usort ($pages, array("PLUGIN_PAGES", "mySort"));
```

No error. It appears to run but `$pages` is still not sorted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function should return an integer less than zero 0, equal to 0, or greater than 0 depending on the comparison. You can do this shorthand with the spaceship operator:

```
public function mySort($a, $b)
{
    return $a->title <=> $b->title;
}
```

This is essentially equivalent to:

```
public function mySort($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->title < $b->title) {
        return -1;
    }
    if ($a->title > $b->title) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For older versions of PHP, you can use @Dharman's suggestion:

```
public function mySort($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->title, $b->title);
}
```

Comment: I have this error with your suggestion... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in

Comment: @SpaceDog you are probably using the old PHP version still. Try to upgrade to the latest version otherwise try `strcmp`

Comment: You have an old version of PHP that doesn't have it. You'll have to write out the conditions or use @Dharman's suggestion.

Comment: Though, to be fair -- any version of PHP that doesn't have the spaceship operator has been end-of-lifed.

Comment: Actually "The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero" It doesn't need to be -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: working now. I had a typo on another part of the code. Thanks guys!